# drill through a measure/summary table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a requirement to drill down from a summarized table to the actual data.

I have created a summary table as bellow using the columns.

bagrespinfo_acftnumber_column,
bag_tag_ispriority_column,
bagrespinfo_arrivalstation_column
, and I want to go to the actual data on clicking any of these numbers in the graph. In this case on clicking on 2149 I want the actual data that constuites to it to be shown in the bellow table.

[image]

Or I have created measure using the columns and added them to a visualization I want to go to the underlying data on clicking 487,020.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

I have tried using a measure and summarized table and didn't seem to work.